# Add new user on button click in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have following code

[my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-silence-cfwey)

I have a button "add", and when I am clicking "new user" was added in my array.

But it works only the first time when I  am clicking second, third.... times nothing was happening.
how many times I click so many times "new user" should be added into an array.

like this.

[image]

I am using functional components and useState hook.

Please help me resolve that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your Add.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Add() {
  const [addNew, setAddNew] = useState([]);
  function add() {
    // HERE is the change, you need to keep the previous values 
    setAddNew([...addNew, <NewUser />]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={add}>Add </button>
      <div> {addNew} </div>
    </div>
  );
}
const NewUser = () => {
  return (
    <p>
      <div>New User </div>
    </p>
  );
};

export default Add;
```

addNew - is the state, in this case, an array.

setAddNew - is the function to handle the State, but you need to handle the logic

Answer (score 1):

Put the `<NewUser />` inside of the `setAddNew([...addNew])`array. Check the following code:

```
function add() {
   setAddNew([...addNew, <NewUser />]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are resetting the value of array for pushing new value to it you have to use

```
setAddNew((old) => [...old, <NewUser />]);
```

this will copy your old array and will also insert the new element to it

Answer (score 0):

In the `Add.jsx` what needs to change is:

```
  function add() {
    setAddNew(<NewUser />);
  }
```

into...

```
  function add() {
    setAddNew([...addNew, <NewUser />]);
  }
```

The previous function would keep resetting `<NewUser/ >` with itself, thus being only 1.

When adding the previous `addNew` state via `...addNew` within an array `[]`, thus being `[...addNew, <NewUser />]`, this will take the previous state of `addNew` and add a `<NewUser />` on top of that.